# Extracting information from xml using XDOCUMENT and LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Consider the following xml file:

```
<UPDATES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EXAMPLES>
    <EXAMPLE>
        <EXAMPLEID>1234</EXAMPLEID>
        <TYPES>
            <TYPE>
                <TYPEID>0</TYPEID>
                <FILES>
                    <FILE>
                        <FILENAME>fileName1</FILENAME>
                        <URL>http://somehwere</URL>
                        <MD5>2d774faa197fe87a49db0709048b82f0</MD5>
                    </FILE>
                    <FILE>
                        <FILENAME>fileName2</FILENAME>
                        <URL>http://somehwere</URL>
                        <MD5>1232132135a4dfseaf321daf51eaf321</MD5>
                    </FILE>
                </FILES>
            </TYPE>
        </TYPES>
    </EXAMPLE>
    <EXAMPLE>
        <EXAMPLEID>5678</EXAMPLEID>
        <TYPES>
            <TYPE>
                <TYPEID>0</TYPEID>
                <FILES>
                    <FILE>
                        <FILENAME>fileName3</FILENAME>
                        <URL>http://somehwere</URL>
                        <MD5>1232132135a4dfseaf321daf51eaf321</MD5>
                    </FILE>
                    <FILE>
                        <FILENAME>fileName4</FILENAME>
                        <URL>http://somehwere</URL>
                        <MD5>1232132135a4dfseaf321daf51eaf321</MD5>
                    </FILE>
                </FILES>
            </TYPE>
        </TYPES>
    </EXAMPLE>
</EXAMPLES>
```

I want to extract the filename and the md5 but only for one particular exampleid.

So far to extract the information I want I've got:

```
var files = xDocument.Descendants("FILE")
                                 .Select(
                                     node => new {FileName = node.Element("FILENAME"), Hash = node.Element("MD5")})
                                 .Distinct();
```

This returns information include the tag. If I do a node.Element("FILENAME").Value I get a null reference exception..

It's on trying to add the Where clause that I'm having the problem.

How Would I specify that I just wanted the filenames and md5s associated with exampleid 1234 returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use casting of nodes instead of accessing value directly. In case node not found you will get NullReference exception while reading Value property. But you will simply get null while casting node to string or nullable type. Here is complete query:

```
var files = from e in xDocument.Descendants("EXAMPLE")
            where (int)e.Element("EXAMPLEID") == exampleId
            from f in e.Descendants("FILE") // get files of particular example
            select new {
                FileName = (string)f.Element("FILENAME"),
                Hash = (string)f.Element("MD5")
            };
```

For exampleId equal to `5678` it returns:

```
{ FileName = fileName3, Hash = 1232132135a4dfseaf321daf51eaf321 }
{ FileName = fileName4, Hash = 1232132135a4dfseaf321daf51eaf321 }
```

---

Same with fluent syntax:

```
var files = xDocument.Descendants("EXAMPLE")
                     .Where(e => (int)e.Element("EXAMPLEID") == exampleId)
                     .Descendants("FILE")
                     .Select(f => new {
                         FileName = (string)f.Element("FILENAME"),
                         Hash = (string)f.Element("MD5")
                     });
```